# JuiceUI Slider - ValueChanged event not firing

Tags: juice-ui

I'm trying to include a JuiceUI Slider control inside a ASP.NET GridView control where each row will have a unique slider control. As a test I created a Slider control:

```
<juice:slider ID="MasterThresholdSlider" Value="50" Min="0" Max="100" runat="server"
Step="25" ValueChanged="MasterThresholdSlider_ValueChanged"></juice:slider>
<asp:TextBox ID="MasterThresholdText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now from the documentation I have read, I can detect the value being changed when the ValueChanged event is raised. So in the code behind I have created the following:

```
protected void MasterThresholdSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Juice.Slider slider = (Juice.Slider)sender;

   MasterThresholdText.Text = slider.Value.ToString();
}
```

For some reason the event doesn't fire when I run the application (breakpoint is at the beginning of the event). Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add AutoPostBack="true" to the juice:slider control to initiate an autopostback. Otherwise that event won't fire until something else on the page triggers a postback.

Comment: I ended up using jsRender so that I could continue using client side HTML controls. I have yet to try this but I'll assume that this is the answer. Thank you.